# Laravel repository update Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Hi I am trying to update a single user by an there `id` in there profile section. If there are no validation errors this works fine, however if I remove the username I get thrown an error as below:

`Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed`

Instead of the validation error message which I would have expected, can anyone advise what this means and how I can resolve this? I'm using a custom repository to handle DB interactions. My profile controller has this function:

```
public function updateProfileuser($id)
    {
      $updateprofileuser = $this->profile->findUserbyid($id);

      if($updateprofileuser)
      {
        $updateprofileuser = $this->profile->updateProfile($id, Input::all() );

          return Redirect::to('/profile')->with('success', 'Updated Profile');
        } elseif(!$updateprofileuser)
              {
                  return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($this->profile->errors); 
              }
    }
```

And the updateProfile() function in my repo is as so:

```
public function updateProfile($id) {

     $rules = array(
        'username' => 'required',
        'email'    => 'required'
    );

    $validator = \Validator::make(\Input::all(), $rules);

       if($validator->fails() ) {
        $this->errors =   \Session::flash('errors', $validator);

        } else {

            $user               = \User::find($id);
            $user->firstname    = \Input::get('firstname');
            $user->lastname     = \Input::get('lastname');
            $user->username     = \Input::get('username');
            $user->email        = \Input::get('email');
            $user->save();
        }
}
```

and my errors function within my repo is as so:

```
  public function errors()
  {
    return $this->errors;
  }
```

and my repo interface

```
public function updateProfile($id);

public function errors();
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong in passing back the error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
 $this->errors =   \Session::flash('errors', $validator);
```

You are trying to serialize the $validator object into the flash session,

So just change it to this:

```
$this->errors = $validator;
```

Although I advise you to refractor your code, I'm a bit confused with what you are trying to accomplish so this is just a suggestion.

Your updateProfileuser function:

```
public function updateProfileuser($id)
{
  $updateprofileuser = $this->profile->findUserbyid($id);

  if($updateprofileuser)
  {

    $rules = array(
      'username' => 'required',
      'email'    => 'required'
    );

    $validator = \Validator::make(\Input::all(), $rules);

    if($validator->fails()){
      return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
    }else{
      $this->profile->updateProfile($id);
      return Redirect::to('/profile')->with('success', 'Updated Profile');
    }

  } else{
    //I don't know what you expect to pass here when $this->profile->findUserbyid($id) doesn't find anything
    $this->profile->errors = 'Id not found';
    return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($this->profile->errors);
  }
}
```

And your updateProfile function:

```
public function updateProfile($id) {
  $user               = \User::find($id);
  $user->firstname    = \Input::get('firstname');
  $user->lastname     = \Input::get('lastname');
  $user->username     = \Input::get('username');
  $user->email        = \Input::get('email');
  $user->save();
}
```